# How to create a dynamic radio button in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to find a tutorial or instruction to create a dynamic radio button but I can't find a good one. I want to use it to change the view when I selecte one button.

If anyone has used it or know a tutorials or a link, please let me know how to do it. It will be such a big help for me.

Thank you,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Platform,StyleSheet,Text,View,Button ,Alert} from 'react-native';
import RadioButton from 'radio-button-react-native';
export default class Taxi extends React.Component {


constructor (props){
super(props)
  this.state = {
        value: 0
    }

    }

handleOnPress(value){
this.setState({value:value})
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text> Ici c'est le taxi!</Text>

       <Text style = {{ color : "lightblue"}}> Nombre de places requises </Text>
       <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={0} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
            <Text> 1 </Text>
             </RadioButton>

             <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={1} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
             <Text> 2 </Text>
             </RadioButton>

             <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={2} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
             <Text> 3 </Text>
             </RadioButton>

             <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value= {3} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
             <Text> 4 </Text>
             </RadioButton>

             <RadioButton currentValue={this.state.value} value={4} onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this)}>
             <Text> 5 </Text>
             </RadioButton>

      <Button style = {styles.buttonStyle} title = 'Request' onPress = {() => {}}/>

    </View> 
  );
}
```

}

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle :{
     color :"blue",
     paddingTop : 80,
     paddingRight :10,

  },
  textStyle: {
    paddingTop : 30 ,
    paddingRight :10,

  }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

//Install using this command

```
npm i react-native-simple-radio-button --save
```

//Add this in the import section

```
import RadioForm, {RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
```

//After Imports add this variable

```
var radio_props = [
  {label: 'param1', value: 0 },
  {label: 'param2', value: 1 }
];

export default class RadioButton extends Component { 

this.state = {value: ""}
```

//add this code in render function

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={radio_props}
          initial={0}
          onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
});
}
```